# Let $B = \{\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}: n=1,2,3, \cdots\}$, find the limit points of $B$.(Where is the error in my solution?)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B = \{\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}: n=1,2,3, \cdots\}$, find the limit
points of $B$.

I solved the problem in the following way:

Firstly, we define a sequence $b_n=\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}.$ We note that, $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0.$ Thus, we have that, $B$ itself is, a convergent sequence in it's own right. So, $0$ is the only limit point of $B.$ For if, there exists a different limit point, say $L$ which was not equal to $0$, then, from the definition of a limit point of a set , we know that, there must exist a convergent (sub)sequence in $B$ that converges at $L\neq 0.$ But this is absurd, for we have the result, that all convergent subsequences of a convergent sequence converges at the same point. So, $\{0\}$ is the only limit point of $B.$

---

However, the answer given is, $\{-1,1\}.$  I don't understand where is the error in my solution as everything seems fine. Any help regarding this, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: No, $b_n=\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}.$ does *not* converge to zero.

Comment: $n/(n+1)$ converges to $1$, not to zero.

Comment: @MartinR Oh! What an error from my end. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b_n\not\to 0$. The quotient $$\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+1/n}\to 1,$$ since $1/n\to$. Now, take the subsequence $$b_{2n}=\frac{(-1) ^{2n}2n}{2n+1}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}\to 1,$$ and the subsequence $$b_{2n+1}=\frac{(-1) ^{2n+1}(2n+2}{2n+3}=-\frac{2n+2}{2n+3}\to -1. $$ These two subsequences form a partition of the set $B$ and they both converge, so the limit points are $\{-1, 1\}$.

Comment: $n/(n+1) $ does not converge to 0, it does to  1. In the infinity, the numerator and denominator have the exact dame Beahivour

Comment: Oh! Thanks! But how to be sure that $\{-1,1\}$ are the only limit points ?

Comment: The set $B$ is just a sequence, the limit points of a sequence are the limits of the subsequences

Comment: Ok, but then how do you imply that no other convergent subsequences exist ? Sorry, if I sound stupid. Is there a theorem related to it?

Comment: Because the two subsequences i wrote form   a partition of the whole sequence, i.e., their union is the whole sequence. Since each of them converges, they have only one limit point, so there are only two limit points of the whole sequence

Comment: In general, can we say, that if , an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)$ has two two convergent subsequences $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n-1})$ converging to $L_1$ and $L_2$ respectively, then $(x_n)$ has only two limit points possible (which are  $\{L_1,L_2\}$ ) ?

Comment: Only if as sets we have $(x_{2n}) \cup (x_{2n+1}) =(x_n) $. There could be more Than two convergent subsequences, even infinitely many.

Comment: But isn't $(x_{2n}) \cup (x_{2n-1}) =(x_n)$ always  true? As, a number is either even or odd ?

Comment: Yes, but it can be that as isolated sequence, $(x_{2n})$ have another convergent subsequence (a sub subsequence) of the original) to a different limit point.  Think for example in the sequence $1, 2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3...etc$.  In that case the partition of the sequence in convergent subsequences is $(x_{3n}), (x_{3n+1}), (x_{3n+2})$

Comment: That is true, only if $(x_{2n})$ is not convergent. If it converges, then $(x_{2n})$ as an isolated sequence has all it's subsequences converging,  at the same point.( Isn't it?) Also, say, $(x_{2n})$ is *not a convergent subsequence,* then is there any *standard algorithm* to find *convergent subsequences of $(x_n)$ ?* In other words, is there any standard way to find limit points of  a set ?

Comment: In general no, there are many stastegies depending on the set

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get it.